# VSTO: Outlook asks 3 times for "Save changes?" ... why?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Here's my simple steps to produce my problem with the code below...

1. Run project
2. Create new mail
3. Add an attacment
4. Close the mail - and I'm asked first time to save changes - I select no
5. Close Outlook Application - I'm asked two times to save changes ... why?

Here's my sample code...

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Shared _currentMailItem As Outlook.MailItem


    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler Me.Application.ItemLoad, AddressOf LoadMail
    End Sub


    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub


    Private Shared Sub LoadMail(Item As Object)
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            _currentMailItem = TryCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.Open, AddressOf OpenMail
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Shared Sub OpenMail(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentMailItem.EntryID) Then
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.AttachmentAdd, AddressOf MailItem_AttachementAdded
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.Close, AddressOf MailItem_Close
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Shared Sub MailItem_AttachementAdded(e As Outlook.Attachment)
        For Each a As Outlook.Attachment In _currentMailItem.Attachments
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Shared Sub MailItem_Close(ByRef cancel As Boolean)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentMailItem.EntryID) Then
            RemoveHandler _currentMailItem.AttachmentAdd, AddressOf MailItem_AttachementAdded
            RemoveHandler _currentMailItem.Close, AddressOf MailItem_Close
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can you see why it asks my twice when closing the app to save changes?

Furthermore I'm uncertain when to use Marshal.ReleaseComObject() - like in my `For Each a As Outlook.Attachment In _currentMailItem.Attachments` ... do I Marshal.ReleaseComObject(a) in the loop?

Thanks

---

UPDATE....

This code still fails eventhough I try to release the objects...

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private _currentMailItem As Outlook.MailItem


    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler Me.Application.ItemLoad, AddressOf LoadMail
    End Sub


    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
    End Sub


    Private Sub LoadMail(Item As Object)
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            _currentMailItem = TryCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.Open, AddressOf OpenMail
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub OpenMail(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentMailItem.EntryID) Then
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.AttachmentAdd, AddressOf MailItem_AttachementAdded
            AddHandler _currentMailItem.Close, AddressOf MailItem_Close
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub MailItem_AttachementAdded(e As Outlook.Attachment)
        For i As Integer = 0 To _currentMailItem.Attachments.Count - 1
            Dim a As Outlook.Attachment = _currentMailItem.Attachments(i + 1)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(a)
            a = Nothing
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub MailItem_Close(ByRef cancel As Boolean)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentMailItem.EntryID) Then
            RemoveHandler _currentMailItem.AttachmentAdd, AddressOf MailItem_AttachementAdded
            RemoveHandler _currentMailItem.Close, AddressOf MailItem_Close
        End If
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_currentMailItem)
        _currentMailItem = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't release underlying COM objects in the code instantly. Holding a reference to the object closed by a user causes such dialogs.

Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article.

Use the `For` loop instead of `ForEach` one. The latter doesn't allow to release all underlying COM objects instantly. You may find the [When to release COM objects in Office add-ins developed in .NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/) page helpful.

Comment: I tried updating my code with your suggestions, but it still fails asking me to save changes 3 times ... any idea?

Comment: In the initial post (at top) ... created a "UPDATE" section.